# Nuxt build on production failed: SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: amazon-web-services, nuxt.js

Im breaking my head over this, i've been searching for hours and trying everything, from downgrading nuxt to tracking back in my older commits to see what changed.

I get the following build error on AWS codebuild:

```
> nuxt build
--
165 |  
166 | /application/dotoo-web/node_modules/@nuxt/utils/node_modules/consola/dist/shared/consola.4bbae468.cjs:473
167 | if (codePoint >= 0x3_00 && codePoint <= 0x3_6F) {
168 | ^^^
169 |  
170 | SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
171 | at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
172 | at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
173 | at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
174 | at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
175 | at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
176 | at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
177 | at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
178 | at Object.<anonymous> (/application/dotoo-web/node_modules/@nuxt/utils/node_modules/consola/dist/index.cjs:5:15)
179 | at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
180 | at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
181 | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
182 | npm ERR! errno 1
183 | npm ERR! dotoo-web@2.36.0 build: `nuxt build`
184 | npm ERR! Exit status 1
```

Im using Nuxt 2.17.0 and i'm pushing to a aws codebuild pipeline that was build by a third party for us. It seems it's still on Node 10 according to this line in the build log: `Status: Downloaded newer image for node:10-alpine`

Does anybody have a clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message refers to the use of a numeric separator in Node.js, which is not supported in Node versions prior to 12.8.1.

```
167 | if (codePoint >= 0x3_00 && codePoint <= 0x3_6F) {
```

`0x3_00` here uses a numeric separator `_`. Without it, the notation would look like `0x300`.

See https://node.green/#ES2021-features--numeric-separators for the list of Node.js versions that support this feature.

So looks like you need to upgrade `node:10-alpine` to at least `node:12-alpine` or better `node:14-alpine` if 12th doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks! I updated to node `16.17.0` and it worked!